# Partial integration in MATLAB

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

I am working on Fourier Analysis and need to implement Fourier Series in MATLAB. What I want is to do the following:

- Obtain the Fourier Coefficients as a function of n,  $a(n)$,  so that whenever I input say n=2, I get the numeric value of a(2). I need an analytical expression for $a(n)$ something like for example $a(n) = \frac{1}{1+n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $f \in L^{2}[0,1], $ and we are working with the standard orthonormal basis $\{\sqrt2 sin (2k \pi x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup \{\sqrt2 cos (2k \pi x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup \{1\}$

The problem that I am facing with implementing the partial integration in the following step

$a(n) := \int_{0}^{1} f(x).e_{n}(x) dx$

where $e_{n}(x)$ is $\sqrt2 sin (2n \pi x), \sqrt2 cos (2n \pi x)$ or 1.

So for example we take $e_n(x) = \sqrt2 cos(2n\pi x)$. 
Let $g(n,x) = f(x).\sqrt2 cos(2n\pi x)$.
How do I get the expression for $a(n)$ i.e.,

$a(n) = \int_{0}^{1} g(n,x) dx$ ?

I want to be able to give n as input to $a(n)$ and obtain the nth Fourier coefficient, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now the things that I have tried are the following,

f = @(x)x;

g = @(n,x)(f(x).*cos(2n$\pi$x));

a_n = @(n)integral(@(x)g,0,1);

So then if I try to obtain a_n(2), I get the following error

Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'function_handle'.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 76)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 89)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in @(n)integral(@(x)g,0,1)

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
syms x n f(x)
assume(n,'integer')
assumeAlso(n > 0)
raw = int(f * cos(2*sym(pi)*n*x), 0, 1);
a(n) = simplify(subs(raw,f,x^2))
```

which produces
$$\frac{1}{2n^2\pi^2} \enspace. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upon running this code I am getting this error:
Warning:
 
Explicit integral could not be found. 
The following error occurred converting from symfun to double:
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in sample (line 7)
a(n) = simplify(subs(raw,f,x^2));

Comment: PS: I am using MATLAB 2013. Just to make sure I don't have outdated libraries.

Comment: It's quite possible that MATLAB's symbolic engine has improved since 2013.  (I don't have an old version installed to double check.)

Comment: One thing you may try is to change things a bit and see if your version accepts them that way.  For instance, the next-to-last line could be `raw = int(f * cos(2*sym(pi)*n*x), 0, 1);`

Comment: Thanks @Fabio. Your suggestion to replace raw(n) to raw worked and now my code works. Could you edit your answer to include this edit, as I am not able to do it from my end? Thanks again. :)

Comment: [+1] Very interesting. I have added 2 "edits" to my answer. The second one is for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to do it :

```
 f = @(x)x;
 gc = @(n,x)(f(x).*cos(2*n*pi*x));
 gs = @(n,x)(f(x).*sin(2*n*pi*x));
 for n=0:5
     a(n+1)=integral(@(x)(gc(n,x)),0,1);
 end;
 for n=0:5
     b(n+1)=integral(@(x)(gs(n,x)),0,1);
 end;
 a
 b
```

(I have been obliged to make a shift, using $a(n+1)$ instead of $a(n)$ because unfortunately Matlab doesn't accept 0 indices).

---

Edit 1 : In order to make a step forward in the direction of an explicit expression for the $b_n$ (of course, the $a_n$, beyond $a_0$, are all zero because $f$ is an odd function), I add the idea to change the type of numbers by using rationnals, i.e., I placed a "format rat" right at the beginning of the program. Then I obtained :

$$b_0=0,b_1=-\dfrac{113}{710},b_2=-\dfrac{113}{1420}, b_3=-\dfrac{113}{2130}, b_4=-\dfrac{113}{2840}, b_5=-\dfrac{113}{3550},\cdots $$

A formula of type $b_k=a/k$ was evident, but with which constant $a$ ?

Some minutes later, it became to me evident: 355/113 is the famous approximation of $\pi$ (exact up to 6 decimal places): see (http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/pi/pirat.html).

Thus the most reasonable guess is that, for $k>0$, $ \ b_k=-\dfrac{1}{2 \pi k}$.

---

Edit 2 : I have been baffled by the answer of Fabio Somenzi.

Comment: Thanks @Jean for answering. The reason I need $a(n)$ a function of n and not discrete values as you suggest is because I need the whole spectrum (from n = 1 to $\infty$) of Fourier coefficients to be used in later parts of my work.

Comment: I don't understand, 1) your first sentence is about Fourier **series** ... which use integer-indexed coefficients, not Fourier Transform or Cosine transform. 2) I have fixed your error 3) There is no harm to use $n$ as a real

Comment: Thanks Jean.I am using integer-indexed coefficeints. The spectrum I meant was $n = 1,2,3,...,\infty$. I need to be able to compute these discrete fourier coefficients at any $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$.

Comment: I still don't understand you : it is what I have done. I stopped arbitrarily at $n=5$. May be your question is about an analytical expression such as for example : $a_n=\dfrac{1}{1+n^2}$ ? But please, say me if the small program I have provided works on your machine, and there is no longer a bug ?

Comment: Yes, Jean I tried the code. it has no bug, works perfectly.And yes, I am looking for such an analytical expression. I need a way to generate that analytical expression.
Thanks.

Comment: Now, I understand : the answer is that Matlab is not the right tool for formal computations like that. You have to turn to so-called CAS software, like Mathematica. (Matlab has a small CAS "kernel" but unable, as far as I know it, to produce results like an explicit formula for Fourier coefficients.

Comment: I am going to add an edit to my answer.

Comment: Your observation about $355/113$ is confirmed by the documentation of the `rat` function, which says that rational approximations in MATLAB are obtained by truncating continued fraction expansions.  While I don't keep accurate tabs, my impression is that the symbolic engine in MATLAB has become more usable over the years.  With *live scripts*, the integration in "mainstream" MATLAB has also improved significantly.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi thank you for these interesting comments.